# How can I colorize all merged cells with a sheet of Open Office-Calc?

Tags: calc, openoffice-basic

The title says it all:

I have a spreadshet in Open Office. How can I find out which cells are merged (horizontal and vertical) within the active sheet to colorize them. Horizontally using another color than vertical. Solutions are much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@JohnSUN provided the following macro that searches for merged cells by using `getIsMerged()`, which you can modify to add color.

```
REM Author JohnSUN - johnsun@i.ua
Sub getMergedCells  ' Create an index of merged cells '
Const INDEX_NAME = "Index Of Merged Cells"  ' Name of sheet for a table of contents and header '
Dim oSheets As Variant  ' All sheets of current spreadsheet '
Dim oSheet As Variant   ' Single sheet '
Dim i As Long           
Dim nCount As Long      ' Count of merged cells '
Dim oCellFormatRanges As Variant
Dim oEnum As Variant
Dim oCell As Variant    ' Single cell '
Dim oCursor As Variant  ' Range of mergd cells '
Dim sRes As String      
Dim aRes As Variant     ' Array of all merged cells '
    oSheets = ThisComponent.getSheets()
    aRes = Array(Array(INDEX_NAME))
    For i = 0 To oSheets.getCount()-1   ' For each sheet in current workbook '
        oSheet = oSheets.getByIndex(i)
        oCellFormatRanges = oSheet.getCellFormatRanges()
        oEnum = oCellFormatRanges.createEnumeration()
        Do While oEnum.hasMoreElements()
            oCell = oEnum.nextElement()
            If oCell.getIsMerged() Then
                nCount = UBound(aRes)+1
                ReDim Preserve aRes(nCount)
                oCursor = oSheet.createCursorByRange(oCell)
                oCursor.collapseToMergedArea()
                sRes = "=HYPERLINK(""#"+oCell.AbsoluteName+""";"""+Join(Split(oCursor.AbsoluteName,"$"),"")+""")"
                aRes(nCount) = Array(sRes)
            EndIf
        Loop
    Next i
    If LBound(aRes()) > UBound(aRes()) Then
        MsgBox("No merged cells...")    
    Else
        If oSheets.hasByName(INDEX_NAME) Then oSheets.removeByName(INDEX_NAME)
        oSheets.insertNewByName(INDEX_NAME, 0)
        oSheet = oSheets.getByIndex(0)
        oSheet.getCellRangeByPosition(0, 0, 0, nCount).setFormulaArray(aRes)
        ThisComponent.getCurrentController().select(oSheet.getCellByPosition(0,1))  ' Show new index '
        ThisComponent.getCurrentController().select(ThisComponent.createInstance("com.sun.star.sheet.SheetCellRanges"))
    EndIf
End Sub
```

Source: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-find-merged-cells-in-calc/19109/3

Comment: Thanks a lot, the macro works fine, giving me on a sheet all the names of merged cells in each sheet of the file with their 'coordinates'. But - how can I colorize the merged cells on the actual sheet?

Comment: That should probably be a different question. Or, you could edit this question to post the code you've tried so far, along with links you've researched that talk about how to do this.